# subtract strings with specific width in for recycle

Tags: r, substr, fasta, bioconductor

I am trying to run a for function to extract multiple strings in order from a fasta.
Here is an example(of course the real one is more than 10 thousand)

```
eg <- ATCGACGTCGATGCTGATCGATCGATCGATCGTCAGATCGATCAG
```

And here is my code

```
forsubseq <- function(dna){
  sta <- for (i in 1:floor(width(dna)/100)) {
    seqGC <- Biostrings::subseq(dna, start = 100*i - 99, width = 100) %>%
             Biostrings::letterFrequency(letters = "GC", as.prob = TRUE)
  }
  return(sta)
}
forsubseq(eg)
```

However, nothing happened after running. It really confused me...What I want to obtain is to analyze GC content for each 100 bp...
Could anyone kindly offer advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The library `Biostrings` is not available for the most recent version of R, but one simplified approach would be to split `eg` at every *n* th character then use `lapply` to analyze. In this example I counted the number of "GC" pairs using `str_count` since I dont have the `Biostrings` library but you can change to the `Biostrings::letterFrequency` function:

```
eg <- "ACGACGTCGATGCTGATCGATCGATCGATCGTCAGATCGATCAG"

n <- 10 # you would change to 100

blocks <- seq(1, nchar(eg), n) # prep to separate every n base pairs

splits <- substring(eg, blocks, blocks + n - 1) # separate every n base pairs

lapply(splits, 
       function(x) stringr::str_count(x, "GC")) # replace with Biostrings::letterFrequency
```

The output is a list counting the number of "GC" pairs for each block of `n` characters (here, 10). If you want a vector of integers representing these data, just simply wrap the `lapply` function in `unlist(lapply(...))`

Comment: Thanks It does work! I didnot realize that I could use "separate" before. Actually `DNAStringSet(splits)` has to be used to create inherited objects for analyzing GC content

Comment: Great! Glad it works with your tweaks - if there are no better answers please click the check mark by the answer to help close out this question and clean up the site. Good luck!